# Why is it that my image is not aligned with my other image HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to show another image on top of my existing image when I try to hover on my existing image tag. However when I try to hover on my existing image, the 2nd image doesnt seem to be aligned on the 1st image. It looks like this:

[image]

How do I get the 2nd image to align on my 1st image? This is my current code:

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle;">
  <a href="#" class="gallerypic" style="border-color:Black;border:0;">
    <span class="hoverclose">
      <img src="images/SampleLogo.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
    <span>
    <img id="imageID" src="" width="150" height="150" border="1" style="border-color:Black;"/>
  </a>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
        a.gallerypic{
          width:140px;
          text-decoration:none;
          position:relative;
          display:block;
          border:1px solid #040404;
          padding:3px;
          margin-right:5px;
          float:left;
        }

        a.gallerypic span.hoverclose{
          visibility:hidden;
          position:absolute;
          left:40%;
          top:35%;
          filter:alpha(opacity=50);
          -moz-opacity:0.5;
          -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
          opacity: 0.5;
        }

        a.gallerypic:hover span.hoverclose{
          visibility:visible;
        }
    </style>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: In your HTML part two span's are opening? is it typo error or you have like this.

Comment: You position values are off that's why. Try `top` and `left` 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `span` is positioned absolutely according to the parent `<a>` tag.  Because that `<a>` has padding and a border, you'll need to set to top and left values of the `span` to 4px, rather than the percentage values you have there.

Alternatively, you can set them to 0 and use a margin.

```
a.gallerypic span.hoverclose {
  visibility:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  left:4px; /* 3px padding + 1px border */
  top:4px;
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
  -moz-opacity:0.5;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zmjHL/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use This class

```
        a.gallerypic span.hoverclose{
          visibility:hidden;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0px;
          top: 0px;
          filter:alpha(opacity=50);
          -moz-opacity:0.5;
          -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
          opacity: 0.5;
        }
```

Here is Demo 
[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zry4G/)

Answer (score 1):

You are positioning the image at `left: 40%; top: 35%;` change both values to `0`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J34Yq/)

```
a.gallerypic span.hoverclose{
      visibility:hidden;
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      filter:alpha(opacity=50);
      -moz-opacity:0.5;
      -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
```